# Sorting divs using jQuery - 2 columns, 1 column, 2 columns etc

Tags: html, jquery, sorting

I want to sort divs using jQuery. There are divs with class col-sm-6 and col-sm-12.

It should appear as follows:

```
col-sm-6 col-sm-6
col-sm-12
col-sm-6 col-sm-6
col-sm-12
etc.
```

these are the divs:

```
<div class="row">
    <f:for each="{items}" as="data">
        <div class="col col-sm-{data.width}" data-width="{data.width}"></div>
    </f:for>
</div>
```

and that's the code I have so far:

```
$('.col:not(.d-none)').sort( function(a,b) {
return ???;
}).appendTo('.row');
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: One would usually sort the data first, then render the divs? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can filter the data and therefore the sorting has to be reset each time.

Comment: I think doing it with sort will be hard because it lets you only compare 2 elements. You could generate 2 lists (1 for each column width) and retrieve 1 element from the 12 column list and after that 2 elements from the 6 column list. Repeat until you have the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the programmer suggested to me:

```
    var elementIndex = 1;
    $('.col').each(function(i, obj) {
        if ( !$(obj).hasClass('d-none') ) {
            if ( elementIndex == 3 ) {
                $(obj).removeClass('col-sm-6');
                $(obj).addClass('col-sm-12');
                elementIndex = 1;
            } else {
                $(obj).removeClass('col-sm-12');
                $(obj).addClass('col-sm-6');
                elementIndex++;
            }
        }
    });
```

It's not exactly what i wanted, but ok.